# Some step in sylow theorem got me confused.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $$\gamma : N[H] \to N[H]/H$$ be a canonical homomorphism. Let $K\le N[H]/H$ have order $p$ where $p$ is a prime. Also $H$ is normal and $H$ has order $p^{i+1}$ in a group $G$. Now,

> Then $\gamma^{-1}[K]$ is a subgroup of $N[H]$ and hence of $G$. This subgroup contains $H$ and is of order $p^{i+1}$

How come it has order $p^{i+1}$, Couldn't understand that part. I've came across this in the proof of the First Sylow Theorem.

Comment: Somebody made a typo. If $K$ has order $p$, then $\gamma^{-1}[K]$ has order $p \cdot \lvert H\rvert$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Why?

Comment: For every $x\in K$, the preimage $\gamma^{-1}(x)$ is a coset of $H$, thus has $\lvert H\rvert$ elements.